# Loop To populate values derived from named ranges

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm writing code to automatically generate a summary file. so far it is making a new spreadsheet and naming it correctly, but it won't populate the new spreadsheet. what I want is a loop to go through Sections(1) and put it in a cell, then go to the next cell and put in the value for Sections(2) etc.

---

```
Sub GenerateSummaryFile()

NM = Range("ModelName").Value
OG = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim Sections(6) As Variant

    Sections(1) = Range("Flow1")
    Sections(2) = Range("Flow2")
    Sections(3) = Range("Flow3")
    Sections(4) = Range("Flow4")
    Sections(5) = Range("Flow5")
    Sections(6) = Range("Flow6")


Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
WS.Name = NM
For i = 1 To 6      
   ActiveSheet.Range(i, 3).Value = Sections(i).Value  
Next i   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(i, 3).Value
```

is wrong. What you probably want is this:

```
ActiveSheet.cells(i, 3)
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.range( ActiveSheet.cells(i, 3), ActiveSheet.cells(i, 3))
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.range("A3")
```